# Elonian Grandmaster Cartographer

Tags: guild-wars

Anyone got any good links for this? Or some advice on how to get these last few spots, I'm currently at 99.7%!

A guide or some good tips on how to flush these very few last spots.

I should mention that I've completed Poghan Passage twice as leader and got nothing!

[image: These are the largest parts that I'm missing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you're already using the Cartography Made Easy mod in Texmod, so I'll skip that recommendation. If you're at 99.7% already, there are some glitched areas in Elona that you can head to to try to get that extra .3%.

- During Dzagonur Bastion, run to the portal that would normally take you to Resplendent Makuun. If you run around in this area, you can get an extra 0.1%-0.2% which normally is not required/counted.
- If you're in Marga Coast, you can flag your heroes on the other side of the portal to Sunspear Sanctuary, then shadow step to your hero. Again, you can get an extra 0.1%-0.2% that is usually nonrequired.
- If you still don't have it after that, you can try using Necrotic Traversal or Consume Corpse to jump onto the corsair ships during Chahbek Village. Each ship will add another 0.1% or so.

[Source](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Legendary_Cartographer#Glitched_locations)

Comment: Great tips, I'll give this a go tonight! And with any luck that'll net me 'Elonian Grandmaster Cartographer', 'Legenday Cartographer' and 'Kind of a big deal' :D

Comment: Thanks! http://www.squaresphere.co.uk/gw/gw-map-spots-hack.jpg